How can I get a user google account data?
I'm building an app that requires user age to give user some privilege. I can't ask user to input his age because he can simply lie. Instead I'm looking into TDS (Trusted Data Sources) to get user age/birthday.
1- How can I get user age from google data? Looks like "People API" is the way to do it but I'm not so sure. (JS ideally)
2- What other TDS should I consider?
